# SQL Server : how to insert-into-select-from, with scalar function in select caluse

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert-into

I am having trouble, while inserting data from a select statement having scalar function call. I posted sample script below, and little explanation and question in the comments.

```
---target table (in my case, this is not table variable, but a regular table, here for simplicity to posted this code as table variable to get the idea)
declare @tblItems table (
  Id int identity(1,1)
 ,ItemID int
 ,TranNo varchar(20)
 ,Qty decimal(18,3)
 ,SomeCalculatedValue decimal(18,3) 
)

--a dummay temp table, works like a source table
declare @tblTemp table (
  Id int identity(1,1)
 ,ItemID int
 ,TranNo varchar(20)
 ,Qty decimal(18,3)
 ,SomeCalculatedValue decimal(18,3) 
)
--put some dummy data in target table
insert into @tblItems(ItemID, TranNo, Qty, SomeCalculatedValue)
values
(1, 'GRN-001', 10, 0),
(2, 'GRN-002', 20, 0),
(3, 'GRN-003', 15, 0),
(4, 'GRN-004', 32, 0),
(5, 'GRN-005', 18, 0)
;

--insert 3 new rows in temp table, which later I want to insert in target table
insert into @tblTemp(ItemID, TranNo, Qty, SomeCalculatedValue)
values
(1, 'GRN-006', 6, 0), -- this line is working work fine,
(1, 'GRN-007', 3, 0), -- but this line is having problem, because it is not considering the last line( with TranNo='GRN-006' )
(2, 'GRN-008', 8, 0)

--here is the actual work, I need to read data from temp table to target table
--and the key requirement is the column 'SomeCalculatedValue'
--it should call a scalar function, and within that function I have to perform some calculations based on same target table
--for each ItemID passed, that scalar function will works as: it performs some sort of calculations on existing rows 
--for that particular ItemID, to simplify the understanding you can think of it as Running-Total(not actually running total, but concept 
--is same that each row value will based on previous row value) 

insert into @tblItems(ItemID, TranNo, Qty, SomeCalculatedValue)
select 
 ItemID
,TranNo
,Qty
,[dbo].[GetCalculatedValue] (ItemID, Qty) as SomeCalculatedValue -- this function will perform some calcualations
from @tblTemp


select * from @tblItems
```

I have two tables, `@tblItems` and `@tblTemp`. I have to insert rows from `@tblTemp` to `@tblItems`, but in the select clause of @tblTemp, I used a scalar function, lets say, `GetCalculatedValue(ItemID, Qty)`, which performs some calculations for specific `ItemID` from target table, and for each row it calculates a value which should be inserting in the `@tblItems`. It is not really Running-Total but for the sake for understanding it can think of as running total, because each row value will depend upon last previous lines.

So problem is that when `@tblTemp` has more than 1 row for a particular `ItemID`, it should consider the rows already inserted, but I think this insert-into-select statement will insert all rows at once, so it is not considering the last lines for particular `ItemID` which are in same select statement. You can review the code, I posted some comments also for explanation.